# VBA - AutoFilter by array didn't return big numbers as well

Tags: excel, vba, filter

As shown in the sheets and code below, I wrote a script that autofilters a database by the values in a list that is converted into an array. This list is periodically refreshed with new values that results in varying number of rows and some values may not be contained in the database.

The code mostly works, except that the big numbers (such as 898709914414013000) don't get filtered as part of the result. This means that when I run my script, only the first two results in the database are returned and does not return the rest as expected. Weirdly, that number does get filtered when it is the only row in that list. I formatted the numbers to remove scienfitic notation, if that affected anything.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code or if it needs to be rewritten from scratch.

Sample Database Sheet:
[image]

| Sample Filter List Sheet (no headers, starts from row 1) |
| --- |
| GRP6077045 |
| GRP6077048 |
| GRP6077050 |
| 898709914414013000 |

```
Public Sub FilterByArray()

Dim Database As Worksheet
Dim Dummy_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim count As Integer
Dim list As Variant

Set Database = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set Dummy_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterList")

count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1", Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)))

'If there are no rows in that list, do nothing
If count = 0 Then

'If there are only 1 row in that list, filter by only that result with this code
ElseIf count = 1 Then
Database.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1")

'For two or more rows, following code is used
Else
list = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(count, 1)).Value), ","), ",")
Database.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=list, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
Public Sub FilterByArray()

Dim Database As Worksheet
Dim Dummy_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim count As Integer
Dim list As Variant

Set Database = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set Dummy_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterList")

count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1", Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)))
Debug.Print count
'If there are no rows in that list, do nothing
If count = 0 Then

'If there are only 1 row in that list, filter by only that result with this code
ElseIf count = 1 Then
Database.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1")

'For two or more rows, following code is used
Else
dummy_string = ""
For n = 1 To count
dummy_string = dummy_string & ";" & Dummy_Sheet.Cells(n, 1).Text
Debug.Print dummy_string
Next
list = Split(dummy_string, ";")
Database.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=list, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works exactly as intended for me

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a big problem, i reproduced the error an the failing part is the generation of the list. Excel doesnt know where you have the filter entries. Second thing i would mention is that i think the filtered values have to be in text format without "E^16" or something like that.
This is the code that worked for me

```
Public Sub FilterByArray()

Dim Database As Worksheet
Dim Dummy_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim count As Integer
Dim list As Variant

Set Database = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set Dummy_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilterList")

count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1", Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)))
Debug.Print count
'If there are no rows in that list, do nothing
If count = 0 Then

'If there are only 1 row in that list, filter by only that result with this code
ElseIf count = 1 Then
Database.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1")

'For two or more rows, following code is used
Else
list = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1:A" & CStr(count)).Value), ","), ",")
Database.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=list, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still getting the same problem with the code. The numbers were formatted to remove scientific notation (format cells > custom > 0) if it affects anything

Comment: Can you upload the file anywhere that i can see whats happening there? @RandyCho

Comment: I think there are rules against uploading files so here's a cross-post that has the sample data that you reproduce: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-autofilter-by-array-doesnt-work-if-list-only-has-1-or-0-rows-of-data-big-numbers-are-not-filtered-too.1158305/

Comment: I didn´t find a solution i tried a lot. But i found one reason why it can´t work as it is now. The split and join of the list splits at "," and bc the number has a "," right after the first digit it splits each of the big numbers in two.  list = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Dummy_Sheet.Range("A1:A" & CStr(count)).Value), ";"), ";") Use this instead.

Comment: Is there another way to auto filter based on that list (which periodically changes)? Since my current code isn't working

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know any other.